# Gearman addTaskBackground complete callback does not fire

Tags: php, callback, background-process, gearman

I am trying to run some job in background and write the result to file result from complete callback, but it does only work for `addTask` (not in background) and not for `addTaskBackground`.

Does someone have an idea?

```php
$client = new GearmanClient();

$client->addServer('localhost');

$client->setCompleteCallback("complete");
$client->addTaskBackground('upload', 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=o3mP3mJDL2k', null, 1);
$client->addTaskBackground('upload', 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SgAVnlnf8w0', null, 2);

/* in these case complete callback works
$client->addTask('upload', 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=o3mP3mJDL2k');
$client->addTask('upload', 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SgAVnlnf8w0');
*/

$client->runTasks();

function complete($task){
    file_put_contents('/home/vonica/public_html/test/tmp/1.txt', $task->unique() . ", " . $task->data() . "\n", FILE_APPEND);
}
```

```php
$worker = new GearmanWorker();
$worker->addServer('localhost');

$worker->addFunction('upload', 'uploader');

while($worker->work()){
    if ($worker->returnCode() != GEARMAN_SUCCESS) {
        echo "ret code: " . $worker->returnCode() . "\n";
        break;
    }
};

function uploader($job){

   $content = $job->workload();
   exec ('echo $( youtube-dl -f worst "'.$content.'")');
   return $content;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CompleteCallback` will not be called on **background** task completion. If you want to check the status of background job use `GearmanClient::jobStatus`.

Client.php

```
// save this $job_handle somewhere
$job_handle = $client->doBackground('upload', 'http://youtube.com/watch?v=o3mP3mJDL2k', null, 1);
```

Status.php

```
// use previously saved job handle to check job's status
$job_handle = $_GET['job_handle'];
$stat = $client->jobStatus($job_handle);
echo "Running: " . 
     ($stat[1] ? "true" : "false") . 
     ", numerator: " . 
     $stat[2] . 
     ", denomintor: " . 
     $stat[3] . "\n";
```

Read more [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/gearmanclient.jobstatus.php)