# Gearman client should throw error when no worker is running

Tags: php, gearman

If there is no worker is running then how gearman client throws error.I added callback for failures but still it give me no response for failure. Please look the below code

client.php

```
   $client = new GearmanClient();
   $complete = 0;
   $fail = 0;
   $client->addServer($server, $server_port);

   $client->setFailCallback(function () use (&$fail) {
   $fail++;
   error_log(__FILE__." ".__LINE__." :FAILED: \n",3,"/var/www/tmp.txt");       
 });
 $client->doLowBackground("write_log");
 $exec = exec('gearadmin --workers | grep pushers_', $output, $res);
 $pri = $client->runTasks();

 if ($client->returnCode() != GEARMAN_SUCCESS)
 {
   error_log(__FILE__." ".__LINE__." :STARTED: ".$client->returnCode()." \n",3,"/var/www/tmp.txt");
   echo "bad return code\n";
   exit;
 }
```

How do i know that even if gearman server is working but no worker is started then if client calls how should i know there is no worker is running.

Comment: Gearman executing jobs when worker is again started running again.So   sorry for the question. I did not know about that. Till that time it is saved in queue. But Can i test when gearman job is failed ?

Comment: for background jobs use `jobStatus` method. Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21656299/gearman-addtaskbackground-complete-callback-doesnot-fire

Answer (score 0):

Gearman acts as a job queuing engine. As such when there are no workers running the job remains in the queue but does not go into error, this is a deliberate feature of the system designed so that if you need to take workers offline for some reason such as code refactoring, maintenance, etc, the jobs can still be submitted to gearman and wait until the workers are re-initialized. If you need to monitor gearman you can use the gearmand query for getting a list of available workers which will return a list of available workers on the gearman server.